# Passing C# custom objects in Session between asp.net web pages

Tags: asp.net

I have a frustrating issue when trying to pass a custom object from 1 page of a web site to another.  When I try to use the object from session on the page 2 it is null.  I believe that my syntax is correct as when I take the code out of my larger solution and run it on it's own it works fine.

I am wondering if there are any settings in visual studio, aspx files, project properties that may be set on my project that may be causing this session object not to work?

Simplied syntax that I am using is;
on page1

```
Person p = new Person;
p.name = "john"; 
p.secondName = "doe";
Session["person"] = p.
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx")
```

Page 2 on page load method

```
Person p = (person)Session["person"]
textbox1.Text = p.name;
textbox2.Text = p.Secondname;
```

As I said this code works fine on it's own but not as part of my larger works project. Any ideas on why this may not be working would be greatly appreciated

Comment: While your syntax is off, there is nothing stopping this from working.  We need a little more context into why it may not be working in your larger project. Does it use an out-of-proc session manager? At what point in the page's lifecycle are you trying to read/write from session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possible options.

First one is that inside your larger project session state is disabled. Please visit [Turn Off ASP Session State in Active Server Pages and IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244465) for more details.

Second option would be that exception occurs somewhere inside your application (separate thread) resulting in application restart and session state loose. You can check this by hooking to Application error inside Global.asax like this:

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    }
```

The last option would be that session["person"] value is changed in other module or page.

Comment: Gregor thanks your post helped me get to the answer.  I didn't really give you enough detail to answer this but thanks to your suggestion I got to the bottom of it.  Problem was I was redirecting to a page in a different project listening on a specific port and for some reason this corrupts the session state.  I moved the page into same project and used relative page redirect and it worked fine.

Comment: @AlexWray : Since your are switching between two different projects, so you need to cache your objects in between them. You should look into WebGarden Concept where there are few projects sharing similar objects. You can use NCache  for the same. Below are the two links that might help you

1. http://abhijitjana.net/2010/10/01/what-is-the-difference-between-web-farm-and-web-garden/, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/web-farm-and-web-garden/

2. Caching : http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/

Comment: Thanks Amit, I will check these out

Answer (score 0):

Try code with,

```
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx", false);
```

Comment: Tried that and still no joy I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

See as per your code if there is database connected then i suggest you to do whatever you want to on page1 and save it to db in single or multiple tables, depending upon the requirements. Now paas the id to page2 as querystring. Format looks like

`Response.Redirect("~/page2.aspx?id=67");`
where is the dynamic unique id from database. Now on page 2.aspx query on the id you have passed.

Comment: Hi Amit, this wouldn't have worked for me as I needed to pass object to page 2 where the user could change data in that object prior to it being persisted to the database.  I have the answer now but thanks for the idea!